# Python subprocess: streaming stout, error codes and terminating

Tags: python, subprocess

I have put together a little generator that takes a video stream URL, transcodes it, and pipes it back.

```
def stream(link):
    ffmpegcmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        #"-loglevel",
        #"panic",
        "-i",
        link,
        "-vcodec",
        "copy",
        "-f",
        "mp4",
        "-movflags",
        "frag_keyframe+empty_moov",
        "pipe:",
    ]

    try:
        ffmpeg_sb = subprocess.Popen(
            ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )

        #ffmpeg_sb.communicate()
        #print(ffmpeg_sb.poll())

        for stdout_line in iter(ffmpeg_sb.stdout.readline, ""):
            yield stdout_line
    except:
        print("Exception")
        ffmpeg_sb.kill()
        
    print("Finished")
```

It works as expected so long as there are no issues with the source stream and ffmpeg doesn't error out. If that does happen, then my generator never prints `Exception` or `Finished`. As a result each time I try to restart the stream on the client more and more CPU gets used. After doing some research I discovered that adding `ffmpeg_sb.communicate()` enables python(?) to see the exit code of ffmpeg. Only then does a exception get raised and the generator finish. There is a problem though. Calling communicate breaks the stdout pipe so there is no longer a stream being yielded.

Does anyone know how I can solve this so that any errors in ffmpeg close the sub process and it pipes correctly?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need something reading stderr so the the process doesn't block because that pipe is full. `.communicate` creates threads to read stdout and stderr then waits for the process to finish. You can do something similar. A thread to read stderr while your main code reads stdout.

```
import threading
import io

class ConsumePipeThread(threading.Thread):

    """Creates and starts a thread that reads a pipe, optionally writing to
    buf (a io.BytesIO like object)"""
    def __init__(self, pipe, buf=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.buf = buf
        self.start()
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            buf = self.pipe.read(512)
            if not buf:
                return
            elif self.buf:
                self.buf.write(buf)
```

To use it

```
try:
    ffmpeg_sb = subprocess.Popen(
        ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    stderr = ConsumePipeThread(ffmpeg_sb.stderr, io.BytesIO())
    for stdout_line in iter(ffmpeg_sb.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line
    print(stderr.getvalue())
except:
    print("Exception")
    ffmpeg_sb.kill() # <== TODO: If Popen fails, ffmpeg_sb was not assigned
    
print("Finished")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was unable to get it to work. However, based on what you told me, it led me down a google rabbit hole where I eventually came up with this. ` try:
            ffmpeg_sb = subprocess.Popen(
                    ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                )
            for chunk in iter(ffmpeg_sb.stdout.readline, ""):
                yield chunk
                if ffmpeg_sb.poll() is not None:
                    raise StopIteration
        except:
            pass`

Comment: It appears to do what I want. Can you see any issues with it?